# MySQL select distinct from tables?

Tags: mysql

I got a little problem I need to do the following...

Select `province, count(*)` all the rows `DISTINCT` email address and `GROUP BY` province. So I would end up with something like

```
Province | Count(*)
Province | Count(*)
```

So let's say AB has 1500 distinct email addresses and SK has 1200 distinct email addresses

```
AB | 1500
SK | 1200
```

Would be the result, but it doesn't seem to be working if I do a DISTINCT with multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT province, COUNT(DISTINCT email) FROM table GROUP BY province;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT province, COUNT(DISTINCT email) as `count`
FROM table
GROUP BY province
```